# Unable to stop "Kill Chrome" effect

Tags: python, google-chrome, kill-process

I used os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f") to kill opened Chrome browsers using ipynb. However, even after I logged out the ipynb / ananconda and reopen the computer, any Chrome browsers opened by the executed python script will still be closed immediately once they are opened.

How should I stop this kill Chrome effect? Please help.

Comment: How did you use this command in your notebook? Have you tried commenting it out or removing it?

Comment: I imported os and then add this statement at the end of the codes and execute it. I already deleted this statement but even I reboot the computer, the effect still appears.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question?